# Error with Term::ReadKey

Tags: perl

I’m trying to run this script to check genotyped data for imputation with HRC or 1000G using an imputation server, it can be found [here](http://www.well.ox.ac.uk/~wrayner/tools/#Checking). It is perl-based. It has these packages/libraries it is (trying) to load.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;
use Getopt::Long;
use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw(gunzip $GunzipError);
use Term::ReadKey   qw/ GetTerminalSize /;
```

However, it throws an error `Unable to get Terminal Size. The TIOCGWINSZ ioctl didn't work. The COLUMNS and LINES environment variables didn't work. The resize program didn't work. at /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/Term/ReadKey.pm line 362.`

How do I solve this?

Comment: Where/how are you running the script? It expects to be run in a terminal.

Answer (score -1):

Ah. So the question is sort of solved. It turns out the script in particular is expecting to be run in a terminal, which stays open. That is to say: it is not expecting to be run in a submission-system, which is what I was doing. In fact, I need to run it in a submission-system, because the computer cluster doesn't allow for big data to be run in a terminal, and because the data is just to big to keep waiting for the program to finish. Submitting it to a compute node with more power makes more sense.

The developer of the script, [the HRC or 1000G Imputation preparation and checking tool](http://www.well.ox.ac.uk/%7Ewrayner/tools/#Checking), has kindly provided a non-terminal-requiring script. He will put it online, and/or provide it via email.

## solved